# Display the name of current user in horizontal menu

Tags: asp.net, membership

I am using `Asp.Net` built-in `membership framework` , I have a requirement where I need to display the name of the `logged-in` user, my `aspnet_users` table stores the user name something like this `abc001` which is actually the usercode of the user , its user name is stored in another table which is linked to the `aspnet_users` table with a `foreign key constraint`.So how do I display the name of the user from that table in my navigation menu which will be floating towards the right.Much like `Facebook` does , it displays `logged-in` users name in the header.
**Edit:**

```
protected void cmdLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
            {
                HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(txtUsername.Text, false);
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
                FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration, ticket.IsPersistent, "");
                authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
                Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
                GetUserName(); 
                string redirUrl = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(txtUsername.Text, false);
                Response.Redirect(redirUrl);

            }


        }
        public void GetUserName()
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext dt = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var name =( from nm in dt.Users_AdditionalInfos
                        where nm.UserCode== txtUsername.Text.Trim() 
                        select nm).Single();
           Global.UserName=name.FirstName +" "+ name.LastName; 
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

```
Membership.GetUser().UserName
```

...to get the currently **logged in** user.  If the user is not logged in, you will get a *null* value returned by `GetUser()`, so code accordingly.

Comment: but the name is actually stored in a different table which is linked to the built-in table so I think Membership.GetUser().UserName wont give me the name.

Answer (score 0):

Try `User.Identity.Name`

See more about 
[HttpContext.User Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx)

If you need to get a different information from another table you can get the `username` and do something like this

```
MembershipUser userInfo = Membership.GetUser("myUserName");    
Guid guid = new Guid(userInfo.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
```

`ProviderUserKey` is unique for each user and I guess you using that as the foreign key.Since you have `ProviderUserKey` you can get necessary details from your other  table

Answer (score 0):

`User.Identity.Name` 
can be used to access the username of the user. Have a look at this tutorial as it further explains how you can get membership information of user. http://mvctutorialsandguides.blogspot.co.nz/2013/03/mvc-c-sql-membership-provider-how-to.html  Hope this helps.